# How to handle if user enter letter instead of digit?

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I have a TextBox that should only accept digits. I added a required field validator to the TextBox so that the value cannot be empty, but if the user enters a letter or a zero, then the logic fails. How should I handle this?

Comment: probably the easiest way is using your own javascript function for onkeypress event

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft's [Mask Edit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/maskededit/maskededit.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [mask input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin